# Get the value for xmlns from NSXMLElement iOS sdk

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser, nsattributedstring, nsxmlelement

I am working on iOS application and i want to get the namespace of a nsxmlelement.

my **NSXMLElement *query** has the following value in it.

```
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" test="this is value">
<item subscription="to" name="test" jid="test@local"/>
</query>
```

I have used following code to get the xmlns but its not working

```
         NSLog(@"%@",[query attributeStringValueForName:@"test"]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[query attributeStringValueForName:@"xmlns"]);
```

Value for **test** is printed but the value for **xmlns** shows null

Please let me know how to get the value of **xmlns**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `xmlns` is not an attribute. `xmlns` is a namespace definition. You can get it with `[query namespaceForPrefix:nil].stringValue`.

Comment: Something additional when your are using XMPPFramework (I guess), have a look at the header file `NSXMLElement+XMPP.h`. It adds properties like `xmlns` and other very useful helpers when working with XML queries and stanzas. Makes code much easier to read, then working with NSXMLElement directly.

Comment: Unless you're using a wrapper library, the above code should always return nil, because nil isn't a valid prefix value when using the NSXML API.  Instead, you must pass an empty string.